Children holding hands randomly; probability of one being left out
There are $n$ children in a class, assigned to perform the following task:

One child is selected at random and instructed to hold the hand of another randomly selected child
This process continues (two different children are selected, both of whom must have at least one hand free) until no further progress is possible

What is the probability that there will be one child left out at the end?
This seems like a graph theory problem, the children will eventually assemble into some number of circles, but I am not sure how to go about the probability calculation.
For $n = 2$, they are guaranteed to form a 2-circle; the probability is zero
For $n = 3$ (let $A$ and $B$ denote the first two selected):
$AB, C$
Choices for the next selection:
$AB$ causes $C$ to be left out
$AC$ and $BC$ both result in a guaranteed 3-circle
The probability is $\frac{1}{3}$
For $n = 4$:
$AB, C, D$
Choices for the next selection are $AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD$
$AB$ - guarantees two 2-circles; no one will be left out
$CD$ - guarantees either a 4-circle or two 2-circles; no one will be left out
$AC,AD,BC,BD$ - simplify to the previous case (a line of kids with both ends free, and one unconnected kid)
The probability is $\frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{9}$
For $n = 5$:
$AB, C, D, E$
Choices: $AB, AC, AD, AE, BC, BD, BE, CD, CE, DE$
$AB$ - removes them both from the game; simplifies to $n = 3$
$AC, AD, AE, BC, BD, BE$ - result in a line of 3 and 2 unconnected kids; also simplifies to $n = 3$
$CD, CE, DE$ - result in two lines of 2 and one unconnected kid; also simplifies to $n = 3$???
It seems that all higher $n$ simplify into the case for $n - 2$ immediately after the first step.
$P(1) = 1$
$P(2) = 0$
For $n > 2, P(n) = \frac{1}{3}$ if $n$ is odd, $\frac{2}{9}$ if $n$ is even

Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural starting point might be to work it out for small $n$.  Also, note that this is similar to this well known question and it's variants.

Clarification:  in the standard spaghetti problem, it is perfectly possible to tie one end of a strand to the other.  I think your phrase "another randomly selected child" is meant to say that you do not allow this here (children don't hold hands with themselves), but you should clarify.

@lulu thanks for the advice, I seem to have arrived at a solution. Do you know where I can find additional resources regarding the spaghetti problem? I am interested in generalizing this to children with an arbitrary number of arms (it would be of use to a software application I am working on, where self-linking an object is undesirable)

I think just googling "probability Noodle problem" should lead you to a lot of articles...it's a pretty standard question (though mostly people focus on the expected number of loops).
